# Preventing IE from freezing?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tablesorter, freeze

We have a part of our web app that displays a list of actionable items ("Jobs") needing to be worked on. Our model of each Job looks like this:

```
{
  "JobUID": Number,
  "State": "String",
  "FirstName": "String",
  "LastName": "String",
  "DateOfBirth": "dateTime",
  "DateReceived": "dateTime",
  "LastWorked": "dateTime",
  "UserName": "String",
  "ProblemText": "String", 
  "AssignedTo": "String",
  "DateAdded": "dateTime",
  "CallOutStatusUID": Number,
  "Notes": [
    {
      "NoteUID": Number,
      "EntityUID": Number,
      "Content": "String",
      "UserName": "String",
      "EntityTypeUID": Number,
      "CreatedDateTime": "dateTime"
    }
  ]
}
```

There can be 0..n `Notes`. We ask a service through AJAX for all these jobs and use them to fill out a table. We're using the jQuery TableSorter plugin on the table these jobs are going into.

Recently the list has grown to 735 of these jobs with a total of 907 Notes, fiddler reports 450 KB of data was transferred. The table is on a different tab than the starting tab of the page. When you click on the tab that will display this table, IE freezes. To clarify, these are HTML tabs all on one page inside of IE. They are not multiple IE tabs.

IE does not steadily grow in memory when you try to switch tabs (it sits at about 98MB). The process sits at 13% processor usage (on an 8 core machine, which tells me that it's doing everything on a single core since 13% is ~1/8). The process never starts responding again and must be closed with task manager. When hooked to Visual Studio 2012, if I attempt to pause and debug while it's like this, VS reports that it's currently in Native Code. I tried setting a javascript breakpoint before the freeze and stepping into the freeze, but other than a few behind the scenes jquery calls, it does seem to actually be hanging in Native Code.

Our quick fix for awhile was to only show 200 of the jobs at a time and it worked but we want a way to be able to display all jobs. I started working with TableSorter's Pager plugin but it didn't help. The sorter is set to only show 10 rows per page. If, before attempting to change tabs, I check how many rows are in that table, it successfully reports 12 (10 rows per page + 1 header row + 1 filtering row).

Here's how I set up the table (`problems` is an array of the above model):

```
for (var i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
    var style = "odd";
    if (i % 2) { style = "even"; }
    var problem = problems[i];
    rows += "<tr class='" + style + "'><td>";
    rows += problem.FirstName;
    rows += "</td><td>";
    rows += problem.LastName;
    rows += "</td><td>";
    rows += problem.DateOfBirth
    rows += "</td><td>";
    rows += problem.ProblemText;
    if (problem.CallOutStatusUID != null) {
        rows += " - " + GetType(callOutStatus, problem.CallOutStatusUID).Display;
    }
    rows += "</td><td style='text-align:center;width:30px'>";
    if (problem.Notes.length > 0) {
        rows += "<a href='#' onclick='getNotes_click(this, \"JobUID\", GetJob, problems);' id='notes-" + problem.JobUID + "' JobUID='" + problem.JobUID + "' class='lnk_Notes'><img src='images/icon_note.png'></a>";
    }
    rows += "</td><td>";
    if (problem.AssignedTo != null && problem.AssignedTo.toUpperCase() != userName.toUpperCase() && problem.State.toUpperCase() == "WORKING") {
        rows += "<a href='imageviewer?JobUID=" + problem.JobUID + "'>Read Only</a>";
    }
    else {
        rows += "<a href='imageviewer?JobUID=" + problem.JobUID + "'>Get Work</a>";
    }
    rows += "</td><td>";
    rows += problem.LastWorked;
    rows += "</td><td>";
    rows += problem.AssignedTo;
    rows += "</td><td>";
    rows += problem.DateReceived;
    rows += "</td></tr>";
}
$("#ListOfJobs tbody").html(rows).trigger('update');
```

Oddly enough, when setting up this same scenario in our dev environment (instead of prod where we found the problem), we could have upwards of 1000+ jobs with over 2000+ total notes and it would display properly. I've tried deleting the large array after it's put into the DOM but nothing changes. I've also tried deleting `rows` but again, nothing. There are multiple tabs other and I can switch between all tabs freely and the page seems to work up until I try to open the tab containing this table. Changing browsers is not an option. I can't even test in other browsers because our AJAX calls mess up in them and we can't reach this point where we have all the data and want to switch tabs. We don't support IE<10. We do have one dev running IE11 and it also breaks in exactly the same way.

What's causing IE to freeze?

EDIT: I tried changing the last line so that it didn't call the trigger and now the tab loads just fine. Anybody know enough about TableSorter to know why this trigger would have these kinds of issues?

EDIT 2: I redownloaded the tablesorter files and it turns out I'm definitely not using the newest ones. When I switch using the newer ones, everything works fine.

Comment: Exactly how do you *fetch* the data?  How many ajax operations are involved? What does the Firefox or Chrome profiler tell you?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome break because they send `OPTIONS` requests ahead of the AJAX request that the server isn't handling. Since `OPTIONS` fails, it doesn't send the AJAX request. I'm only making one AJAX request.

Comment: It's very odd that in your dev environment it works properly. I do not have a idea of what's is going on. But looking at the different behavior between the environment, could be something in the way the server provides the data. Did you check if the data is being gziped , the charset, or something like that. It could affect the process need to parse the data.

Comment: Well, you've got all the information available. What has the IE profiling tools shown you?

Comment: @JoãoMosmann Our dev environment never got as full as our prod (they each have their own DBs) but I'll look into the gzipping.

Comment: What does that "update" event do?

Comment: @Pointy If I remember properly, it helps keep the filters of TableSorter in tune with what's actually in the table.

Comment: Well have you tried skipping that step (or other similar things) in order to find where in the process things are getting stuck?

Comment: It's not hanging in the above code. It seems to be happening in Native Code that I can't see. The `.trigger('update')` is executing and seems to be finishing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52550/discussion-between-corey-ogburn-and-pointy)

Comment: @Point I left IE trying to change tabs overnight with the profiler running. It never successfully changed tabs and the profiler has come back with nothing.

Comment: Well the thing to do is to track down exactly what the last thing is that the code *successfully* completes. Nobody can really help you do that; you've just got to go through a process of elimination. If it makes it all the way through the code you've posted here, then it's probably got nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer does not support `innerHTML` modifications on `<table>` elements [[citation](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html)]

Therefore, jQuery is having to parse out your large string of generated HTML and manually create every single element, set attributes, attach child nodes, append them... And unless they added code to detach the `<tbody>` element before working on the DOM, the browser is having to recalculate the entire table with *every single operation*.

If possible, change your code so that you are generating a whole table, and replace whatever table you had before with it. This will allow jQuery to use `innerHTML`, which is significantly faster as it uses the browser's internal parser.

Comment: That would make sense if it's hanging on the last line: `$("#ListOfJobs tbody").html(rows).trigger('update');`. Although that line does take a noticeable amount of time to execute, the browser continues past it.

Comment: I think you're at least partly right, but it's odd that they've said it works fine in the "lab".

Comment: Hmm... you mention having tabs? It's possible that the tab plugin you're using isn't very good at particularly large elements like that table?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That makes sense except we have successfully loaded a larger table than this. 1000+ rows.

Comment: Wow... usually I'm good at fixing IE quirks (they almost invariably tend to be someone's fault rather than the browser's XD Bad code, bad plugin...) but this time I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the next best thing to try would be to have the table update called after the tab has been switched, and if possible, remove the table and replace it with a fresh one whenever it reloads. I don't know if you have any event listeners attached to anything on the table, but if not, here's a one-liner to try:

```
$("#ListOfJobs").replaceWith( "<table id=\"ListOfJobs\"><tbody>" + rows + "</tbody></table>").trigger('update');
```